Ubuntu 22.04 - Nautilus - SMB mounts showing up twice on sidebar
I have an ubuntu 22.04 system (gobsmack) that has mounts to an SMB share \foosmb with three shares: alphashare, betashare, deltashare
When I mount the foosmb shares on gobsmack, the entries for alpha/beta/delta are listed twice in gobsmack's desktop Nautilus sidebar.
The issue is with the Nautilus display only - all sidebar entries work in that they're browseable, I can read the files on them, etc.
Approach 1 - mount with fstab in /media folder shows duplicate Nautilus sidebar entries

In gobsmack's /media folder, su mkdir alphashare, betashare, deltashare
In /etc/fstab created entries

//foosmb/alphashare /media/alphashare cifs ,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0


After rebooting, gobsmack's Nautilus sidebar shows two entries each for alphashare, betashare, deltashare.  All are accessible and I can view the files.


Approach 2 - gobsmack /media/foosmb subfolder, also duplicate entries
gobsmack automounts USB drives into media, so I thought it might be automounting the SMB share folders and a subfolder might prevent this.

In gobsmack's /media folder

 su mkdir foosmb/alphashare, foosmb/betashare, foosmb/deltashare


In /etc/fstab created entries

    //foosmb/alphashare /media/foosmb/alphashare cifs ,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0


After rebooting, gobsmack's Nautilus sidebar shows two entries for alphashare., betashare, deltashare. All are accessible and I can view the files.


This is a known bug.
A workaround for older versions is to use x-gvfs-hide in fstab to hide them manually as seen in this answer.
